# How to parallelize sequential stream in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream

I need to build a sort of parallel pipeline. Pipeline consists of 3 steps

1. `readLines()`: read 100.000 lines from filed
2. `firstQuery()`: build and send query to DB using 100.000 lines from readLines()
3. `secondQuery()`: build and send another query using `firstQuery()` results

- `readLines()` takes 1 second, returns `Stream<List<Line>>`
- `firstQuery()` takes 10 seconds returns `Stream<List<FirstResult>>`
- `secondQuery()` takes 2 minutes `Stream<List<SecondResult>>`

No matter what I do with Executors, futures all methods are executed in sequential manner.

I suppose it's because of `readLines()` which returns `Stream<List<Line>>`, but it can't be paralleled since read from file is sequential.

What is the right way to do smth like that:

```
readLines() // limit concurrency to 2 (not more than 00.000 or lines in memory at the same time)
    // as soon as lines are read from file, pass them to async
    1: List<Line> -> firstQuery() -> secondQuery()
    2: List<Line> -> firstQuery() -> secondQuery()
        3: List<Line> -> firstQuery() -> secondQuery()
        4: List<Line> -> firstQuery() -> secondQuery()
            ... more here
                10: List<Line> -> firstQuery() -> secondQuery()
```

How could it look like?
What I've tried

- add parallel to `readLines()` which return `Stream<List<Line>>`

  - no luck
- add parallel, custom executors with Futures to `firstQuery() -> secondQuery()`, no luck still sequential

Comment: If one part cannot be parallelized, do it sequentially. In the given case, read the file, return a `List<Whatever>` and execute the stream-operations on that `List`.

Comment: The Types of the `Stream`s look funny. Are you sure you want a `Stream<List<Something>>`, not a `Stream<Something>`?

Comment: Yes, I read lines from file in batches in order to perform DB query in batches.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how your `readLines()` method constructs the stream?